# Run a function at every iteration of a GLib.MainLoop

Tags: python, glib

I'm writing a simple Python 3 program that uses PyDBus and GLib.

I'm trying to use [PyDBus](https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus) to send a signal whenever an edge event is detected on a Raspberry Pi GPIO pin.

To do that, the function that does this task needs to be called at every iteration of the main loop. I've seen that the [`timeout_add`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) function does a similar action; however, `timeout_add` runs my function only every `interval` milliseconds.

Is there a way to call it at every iteration instead?

Comment: what is wrong with doing every 1-10 milliseconds instead of each iteration?

Comment: It's probably just me being "overly precise" or "demanding". In this use case a few milliseconds can do it, but in other more time-critical use cases it might be a good thing to be able to do.

Comment: no I don't think it is either of those, I'm just thinking a loop like that needs to be really optimized so a "per iteration callback" would not be used very frequently and be an extra check in most cases so it may not exist on purpose for optimization. I agree that other then that it would be a good feature to have.

Comment: The closest thing to what you're asking is probably adding a custom source (i.e., g_source_new, g_source_set_funcs, etc.).  However, the right way to do this would probably be to configure the pin to generate an interrupt and use g_source_add_unix_fd to poll() the descriptor.  That should give you much better performance.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: I really think it must exist for GUIs, which need to check for events and update the view.

Comment: @nemequ that sounds like a good solution; however I wouldn't know how to do that, as even the RPi.GPIO module does not use interrupts to detect events: https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code/ci/default/tree/source/event_gpio.c#l324

Comment: See https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_GPIO_signals for some info on how to do it in C, shouldn't be hard to port to Python.  Since you're using GLib you don't have to worry about calling `poll()`; just get the pins configured then use `g_source_add_unix_fd()`, or you could even use the async functions in GIO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`g_idle_add()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add). It creates a `GSource` with no preconditions, and a low priority, so its callback function is executed once per main context iteration, at a lower priority than other pending events.

If you need to bump the priority, use [`g_idle_add_full()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add-full) similarly.

---

As @nemequ says above, though, the architecturally best solution is to write your own `GSource` implementation (see the documentation for [`GSourceFuncs`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSourceFuncs)), which could behave the same as a source created with `g_idle_add()`, or could improve performance from knowing the specifics of the I/O pin you’re querying. It all depends on the API the kernel exposes for that I/O pin, and how that’s pollable from user space.

There is [documentation on writing a custom `GSource` here](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/custom-gsource.c.html.en).